# ServiceStack OAuth - registration instead login

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth, servicestack

In servicestack OAuth implementation I only saw possibility to automatically login with eg. facebook account.

But is there abbility to support registration process with facebook login. What I wanted is to let users login to facebook app, and then load their Name, Surname and email and prefill needed text boxes for real registration on my site (since I also have to have mobile phone verification etc.) I don't want user to be authorized and authenticated when he logs in with facebook. Only credentials login should be valid one for full site access.

**Edit:** I found a solution.

In FacebookProvider.cs

```
public override bool IsAuthorized(IAuthSession session, IOAuthTokens tokens, Auth request = null)
{
    if (request != null)
    {
        if (!LoginMatchesSession(session, request.UserName)) return false;
    }
    return tokens != null && session.UserName!=null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tokens.AccessTokenSecret);
}
```

The catch was the **&& session.UserName!=null** part. So we can check if user is logged in using credentials, this will be !=null and user can use all services. If not, this will be ==null and he can only get facebook info from session.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [SocialBootstrap API](http://bootstrapapi.apphb.com) project shows an example of handling the callback after a successful Authentication by overriding the [OnAuthenticated() hook of its custom user session](https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi/blob/master/src/SocialBootstrapApi/Models/CustomUserSession.cs):

I've pulled out, rewrote some and highlighted some of the important bits:

```
public class CustomUserSession : AuthUserSession
{
    public override void OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, 
                    IAuthSession session, 
                    IOAuthTokens tokens, 
                    Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
    {
        base.OnAuthenticated(authService, session, tokens, authInfo);

        //Populate matching fields from this session into your own MyUserTable
        var user = session.TranslateTo<MyUserTable>();
        user.Id = int.Parse(session.UserAuthId);
        user.GravatarImageUrl64 = CreateGravatarUrl(session.Email, 64);

        foreach (var authToken in session.ProviderOAuthAccess)
        {
            if (authToken.Provider == FacebookAuthProvider.Name)
            {
                user.FacebookName = authToken.DisplayName;
                user.FacebookFirstName = authToken.FirstName;
                user.FacebookLastName = authToken.LastName;
                user.FacebookEmail = authToken.Email;
            }
            else if (authToken.Provider == TwitterAuthProvider.Name)
            {
                user.TwitterName = authToken.DisplayName;
            }
        }

        //Resolve the DbFactory from the IOC and persist the user info
        using (var db = authService.TryResolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().Open())
        {
            //Update (if exists) or insert populated data into 'MyUserTable'
            db.Save(user);
        }

    }

    //Change `IsAuthorized` to only verify users authenticated with Credentials
    public override bool IsAuthorized(string provider)
    {
        if (provider != AuthService.CredentialsProvider) return false;
        return base.IsAuthorized(provider);
    }
}
```

Basically this user-defined custom logic (which gets fired after every successful authentication) extracts data from the UserSession and stores it in a custom 'MyUserTable'.

We've also overridden the meaning of `IsAuthorized` to only accept users that have authenticated with CredentialsAuth.

You can use this data to complete the rest of the registration.

### Other possible customizations

ServiceStack's built-in Auth persists the AuthData and populates the Session automatically for you. If you want to add extra validation assertions you can simply use your own custom [Authentication] attribute instead containing additional custom logic. Look at the implementation of the built-in [AuthenticateAttribute as a guide](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/AuthenticateAttribute.cs).

Comment: mythz, thanks for answer, but my real problem is that facebook user is automatically authorized for using all [Authenticate()] services. I want only credentials authorized users to be able to access this kind of services.

Comment: I've Updated to CustomUserSession to override meaning of IsAuthenticated.

Comment: I tried your solution, but it seems that IsAuthorized method in my custom session is never called.

Comment: Are you overriding it? It's called by the AuthAttribute here: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/AuthenticateAttribute.cs#L66

Comment: It works now. But your solution still has a problem that later you cannot login with facebook (after registration). My solution works for that case also :)

Comment: //Resolve the DbFactory from the IOC and persist the user info
        using (var db = authService.TryResolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().Open())
        {
            //Update (if exists) or insert populated data into 'MyUserTable'
            db.Save(user);
        }   ...... This bit doesn't seem to be correct as when I put in full namespace of the IDbConnectionFactory the db object doesnt have 'Save' method