# ServiceStack: Get email from auth session when authenticating with Google

Tags: servicestack

I am authenticating users via GoogleOpenIdOAuthProvider. I need to access the email address of the user that logged in. I have attempted to implement the [Using Typed Sessions in ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions) code as-is.

So, I created a base class that my service inherits from:

```
public abstract class AppServiceBase : Service
{
    //private CustomUserSession userSession;
    protected CustomUserSession UserSession
    {
        get
        {
            return base.SessionAs<CustomUserSession>();
        }
    }
}

public class CustomUserSession : AuthUserSession
{
    public string CustomId { get; set; }
}
```

The service has the `[Authenticate]` attribute on it. In my AppHost setup, I have configured auth like this:

```
        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(),
            new IAuthProvider[] {
            new GoogleOpenIdOAuthProvider(appSettings)    //Sign-in with Google OpenId
        }));
```

Once the user has authenticated, the service tries to access the auth session from the base class like this:

```
var x = base.UserSession.Email;
```

However, Email is always `null`. How can I access this value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to pull the data from the AuthProvider and set the value in the CustomUserSession. An example of this is shown in the SocialBootstrapApi sample

https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi/blob/master/src/SocialBootstrapApi/Models/CustomUserSession.cs#L50

Override OnAuthenticated, find the GoogleOpenIdOAuthProvider to get to the email address.

Another example is shown at [ServiceStack OAuth - registration instead login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432426)

Comment: At first, it wasn't clear why this wasn't already done for me, until I realized you could be simultaneously authenticated with multiple providers.