# ServiceStack JsonServiceClient calling remote service

Tags: servicestack

What do you need to do to a JsonServiceClient in order to call a remote service that is secured by oAuth providers (i.e. Facebook, GooleOpenId etc) + AuthenticateAttribute? 
My client has already authenticated against facebook?
How do you configure the JsonServiceClient object here and with what?

Any examples of this? It seems to be a very common scenario of a Xamarin phone app calling a secure and remote web service, that's all we are trying to do here.

Comment: this [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12432835/2103764), is useful to you ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you call an authenticated ServiceStack service once the client is authenticated using OAuth?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18938054/how-do-you-call-an-authenticated-servicestack-service-once-the-client-is-authent)